# Use elements of an array in a function

Tags: function-construction, numeric-array

I have an array that I am importing from a mat file lets call it $A$.
I want to define a function like

```mathematica
F[n_,m_] = m A[[1,n]]
```

But when I do this, I get an error

```
Part: The expression n cannot be used as a part specification.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`:

```
F[n_, m_] := m A[[1, n]]
```

If you use `Set`, then the right had side gets evaluated when you evaluate this definition. Since `n` is just a raw symbol, the `Part` cannot be resolved, and you get the message. The function still works, however (assuming `m` and `n` didn't have values at the time), because even though you get a message, the expression still evaluates (it just evaluates to itself).

`SetDelayed` holds the right hand side unevaluated, and so the expression on the right hand side won't get evaluated until `F` is actually given arguments and those arguments have replaced their corresponding symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica has to know that n,m are positive integers:

Try

```
A = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 5}];

F[n_ /; Element[n, PositiveIntegers], m_ /; Element[m, PositiveIntegers]] :=m A[[1, n]]

F[3,4] (* examplary 3.46614*)
```